# Qt 5.3 adding @debug/mocinclude.tmp to the MOC.exe in windows port

Tags: qt, porting, qmake

i try to port mac application to windows , 
using Qt 5.3 windows 7 and visual studio 2012 . i done several simple projects and all worked fine .
but now i try to port mac application after creating with qmake the VS sulotion
im getting this MOC.exe error :

```
D:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\bin\moc.exe  -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS -DCC_TARGET_QT5 -DUSE_FILE32API -DCC_KEYBOARD_SUPPORT -D__QT__ -DCC_UNDER_QT -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1700 -D_WIN32 @debug/mocinclude.tmp ..\..\cocos\2d\platform\qt\CCApplication.h -o debug\moc_CCApplication.cpp

MOC ..\..\cocos\2d\platform\qt\CCApplication.h
1>  moc: Cannot open options file specified with @
1>  QCommandLineParser: argument list cannot be empty, it should contain at least the executable name
```

when i remove in the command line the @debug/mocinclude.tmp and execute the moc.exe , it generate me the file.

what is wrong here and what im missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this error myself personally, but I have built several complex Qt programs using Visual Studio.

moc.exe uses `QCommandLineParser` (since Qt 5.3) to decide what to do with the list of parameters.  In Visual Studio when it is building a program it doesn't know what to do with the `@debug` because `@` doesn't belong in filenames.  Visual Studio properites and batch files can do replacements when Macro names are used such as `$(Platform)` or `$(Configuration)`.  By the time it gets to execution on the commandline it is replaced with the actual text that the macro represents.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the replay is it new in 5.3? 
do i need to write something in the qmake files ?

Comment: I just know that the release of 5.3 mentioned the creation of `QCommandLineParser`.  Usually I start with a project created using the Qt-Add-On for Visual Studio and add my source files to that.  Or I use Qt Creator and just use the msvc compiler.